# Insert value in different columns

Tags: excel-formula

I need formula for all of this can any one give me the formula for:

Insert 2000 in "I", airplane in "H", Visit in "G"

if "C" is london &  "D" is Newyork

And 
Insert 5000 in "I", airplane in "H", Visit in "G"
 if "C" is Karachi &  "D" is munich

Comment: No, that cannot be done with one formula.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this assuming you're in row 1. Adjust the row number accordingly. You will need a separate formula in each cell (G1, H1, I1, G2, H2, I2, etc.) unless you want to do VBA. If these are the only two columns you're testing then maybe something like this for I1:

`=IF(AND($C1="london",$D1="Newyork"),2000,IF(AND($C1="Karachi",$D1="munich"),5000,"")`

For columns H and G, copy this text and replace the 2000 and 5000 with appropriate values.

If you have a lot more values to test, it may be worthwhile to make a lookup table. In another sheet, make A1=london, B1=Newyork, C1=london-Newyork, D1=Visit, E1=airplane, F1=2000. Fill in rest and sort. Then in your worksheet, use something like this in I1.

`=VLOOKUP(C1&"-"&D1,OtherSheet!A1:F20,6)`